# Best way to trigger and window python beam process that read from google storage on dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I never used beam before, and the whole trigger and window stuff kind of confuse me.

I need to write a program that would run on dataflow, and reads from google storage from a path like this: `node-<num>/<table_name>/<timestamp>/file` (I have multiple from nodes, the tables name are the same per node and I have one file per timestamp) also files are being uploaded there continually. (I would love to avoid using pubsub since I work for a small company and its more money...)

Now since there are multiple nodes there could be some duplicates in the files so I do want to group them by timestamp and from what I've read I need to take that in account to the windowing.

So how should I trigger and window it so that it would run "forever" and with a way for me to group the files by timestamp and remove duplicates?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For what i read, it looks you are going to use batch. If so, is there any reason to want triggers?

Comment: what do you mean by batch? I have a whole python process I need to run using beam to have it run parallelly because we are talking about teras of data

Comment: Is your pipeline batch (bounded data) or streaming (unbounded)?

Comment: its bounded, but how can i do it using batch where everything memory wise and multiprocessing is automatically handled?

Comment: @Iñigo Its already running on a vm as a plain python program that uses while true but it takes too much management and resources so I want to switch to something more managed like google's dataflow

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [File processing patterns](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/file-processing/), continuous read mode is not supported in Python.

You need to use the Java SDK. And you can [assign timestamps](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#adding-timestamps-to-a-pcollections-elements) to each file name matched manually.

Comment: Thanks! but from what I understood from the link you added its not what i want anyway. I want my process to run every few hours get all of the new files that were added between the runs.